# JQGrid setCell customFormatter

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using setCell to set the value of a cell.  The problem is it is still calling the customFormatter specified for the column.  Is there anyway I can set the value of this cell without it having to go through the customFormatter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) will be used on every grid refresh, so to set the cell value you have to do this after the custom formatter. The best place to do this is inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) or [gridComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler.

To set the cell value you can use jQuery.text for example. So you should get jQuery object which represent the cell (`<td>` element) and then use jQuery.text or jQuery.html to change the cell contain. How I understand you, you knows the rowid of the cell and the column name which you want to change. The following code could be:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var rowid = '2', colName = 'ship_via', tr,
        cm = this.p.colModel, iCol = 0, cCol = cm.length;
    for (; iCol<cCol; iCol++) {
        if (cm[iCol].name === colName) {
            // the column found
            tr = this.rows.namedItem(rowid);
            if (tr) {
                // if the row with the rowid there are on the page
                $(tr.cells[iCol]).text('Bla Bla');
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithCustomFormatterAndFilterToolbarSetCell.htm).
[image]